# How to compile via LuaLaTeX in Vim?

Tags: luatex, fontspec, vim, vim-latex

I recently started to use Gnuplot as my plotting solution, and I started to use terminal more and found about Vim, I immediately fell in love with it. I have finally got working latexmk compilation with `vimtex`, but not LuaLaTeX for `fontspec` package.

PS: I am not a programmer...

**This is my 'init.vim' file**

```
  1 call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
  2 Plug 'ervandew/supertab'
  3 Plug 'sainnhe/edge'
  4 Plug 'joshdick/onedark.vim'
  5 Plug 'wadackel/vim-dogrun'
  6 Plug 'arcticicestudio/nord-vim'
  7 Plug 'preservim/nerdtree'
  8 Plug 'dracula/vim', { 'as': 'dracula' }
  9 Plug 'lervag/vimtex'
 10 call plug#end()
 11
 12 source $HOME/.config/nvim/themes/airline.vim
 13 source $HOME/.config/nvim/themes/onedark.vim
 14
 15 set nu
 16
 17 let g:tex_flavor  = 'latex'
 18 let g:tex_conceal = ''
 19 let g:vimtex_fold_manual = 1
 20 let g:vimtex_latexmk_continuous = 1
 21 let g:vimtex_compiler_progname = 'nvr'
 22 let g:vimtex_view_method = 'skim'
 23
 24 " NCM2
 25 augroup NCM2
 26   autocmd!
 27   " some other settings...
 28   " uncomment this block if you use vimtex for LaTex
 29   autocmd Filetype tex call ncm2#register_source({
 30             \ 'name': 'vimtex',
 31             \ 'priority': 8,
 32             \ 'scope': ['tex'],
 33             \ 'mark': 'tex',
 34             \ 'word_pattern': '\w+',
 35             \ 'complete_pattern': g:vimtex#re#ncm2,
 36             \ 'on_complete': ['ncm2#on_complete#omni', 'vimtex#complete#omnifun    c'],
 37             \ })
 38 augroup END
```

I have found those settings here: https://yufanlu.net/2018/09/03/neovim-latex/

Comment: You can set lualatex as the default in your .latexmkrc

Comment: @DG' Where can I find it?:)

Comment: `:!lualatex %`?

Comment: In my `.vimrc` file I have the line `let g:vimtex_compiler_engine = 'lualatex'` and that sets `LuaLaTeX` as the default engine.